# Initialise persistant value on instantiable class based on appconfig

Tags: c#, .net-core

How do I create a persistant value on a class that stays the same each time it is created?

```cs
public record StorageUrl
{
    public string FileName { get; set;}
    public string BaseAddress {get; set;}
    public string FullPath => $"{BaseAddress}/{FileName}";
}
```

I would like the value of BaseAddress to come from a config file.

My current apporach is to inject `IOptions<BaseAddressSettings>` each time I want to initialise a `StorageUrl` is there a way to set the `BaseAddress` without having to inject `IOptions` each time.

I would like to initalise the class like

```cs
var storageUrl = new StorageUrl { FileName = "fileName" };
```

I am currently initalising like so

```cs
var storageUrl = new StorageUrl 
{ 
   FileName = "fileName", 
   BaseAddress = options.BaseAddress
};
```

Comment: There are a lot of options, which depend on details you haven't provided. For example, how do you typically create an instance of `StorageUrl`? One option to consider is to use a factory pattern, where the factory receives the `IOptions` instance using DI, and your application code calls the factory to create instances of `StorageUrl`.

Comment: Hi @JackA. I've updated the question to reflect how I would like to initialise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is no way to inject an `IOptions` instance into the constructor other than doing so from your application code.

One option is to create a non-default constructor that takes the `IOptions` instance as a parameter. So your constructor would look like this:

```
public class StorageUrl
{
    public StorageUrl(string fileName, IOptions<BaseAddressSettings> options)
    {
        FileName = fileName;
        BaseAddress = options.Value.BaseAddress;
    }
}
```

and your application code would look like this:

```
var storageUrl = new StorageUrl("fileName", options);
```

Another option is to use a factory. This is mainly useful when the class has complex creation requirements. So it may be overkill for this application, but it can help your application grow as requirements become more complex.

Factory service:

```
public class StorageUrlFactory
{
    private readonly IOptions<BaseAddressSettings> options;

    public StorageUrlFactory(IOptions<BaseAddressSettings> options)
    {
        this.options = options;
    }

    public StorageUrl Create(string fileName)
    {
        return new StorageUrl
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            BaseAddress = options.Value.BaseAddress
        };
    }
}
```

In your application code, you would inject the factory service using DI and call it to create instances like this:

```
var storageUrl = storageUrlFactory.Create("fileName");
```

Comment: Thanks, first option will work fine, at least it will ensure that the value is set. I was imagining I'd be able to set a static variable on it and regester it within startup but that doesn't seem possible!

Comment: @Matt You could do that but I wouldn't recommend it. Static values and singletons that aren't managed by your DI container tend to become a source of bugs and a hassle to deal with.